# ReactJS disable button dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to ReactJS. I want to disable update button if zipcode length is lessthan 5 or zeroos.

```
let zipCodeButton = true;
function zipCodeChange(event) {
    if (event.target.value.length === 5 && event.target.value !== "00000") {
        zipCodeButton = false;
    }
}


// function isDisabled() {
//  return zipCodeButton;
// }
//const [zipCode, zipCodeChange] = useState("");

const NavigationUtilityZipCode = () => (    
                    <input type="text" id="zip-code-header" className="body-medium" maxLength={5} onChange={zipCodeChange} onKeyDown={(event) => {
                        if (!/[0-9]/.test(event.key) && event.code != "ArrowLeft" && event.code != "ArrowRight" && event.code != "Backspace" && event.code != "Delete" && event.code != "Tab") {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }} />
                <Button jcrTitle="Update Zip Code" primary={false} disabled={zipCodeButton} id="handle-update-zip-code-click"></Button>
);

export default NavigationUtilityZipCode;
```

Comment: Errors: `JSX expressions must have one parent element`; `Button is not defined` – are you sure this code runs? Perhaps you left some lines out? :) Anyway, what have you tried so far to make the button disable? I notice you asked about "hooks" in the title and tag.

Comment: yes, we are using in another component <NavigationUtilityZipCode />

Comment: I want to enable or disable update button dynamically when enter zipccode in the textbox.

Comment: "using in another component" – `NavigationUtilityZipCode` is the component you have provided, but it is invalid React (two adjacent, unnested elements), and includes a component you have not provided nor `import`ed in your provided code.

Comment: "forget about that one" – forgot about which one, what's in your post? "I'm having code like this" – if I'm forgetting what's in your post, what code are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this like this  :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [zipCode, setZipCode] = useState("");
  const [zipCodeButtonVisible, setZipCodeButtonVisible] = useState(true);

  const triggerZipCodeChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setZipCode(value);
    if (value.length === 5 && value !== "00000") {
      setZipCodeButtonVisible(false);
    } else {
      setZipCodeButtonVisible(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="zip-code-header"
        className="body-medium"
        maxLength={5}
        onChange={triggerZipCodeChange}
        onKeyDown={(event) => {
          if (
            !/[0-9]/.test(event.key) &&
            event.code !== "ArrowLeft" &&
            event.code !== "ArrowRight" &&
            event.code !== "Backspace" &&
            event.code !== "Delete" &&
            event.code !== "Tab"
          ) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        }}
        value={zipCode}
      />
      <button
        disabled={zipCodeButtonVisible}
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("You can call any function here ");
        }}
      >
        Update Zip Code
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Explanation :**

Initially we set button to disables  and In triggerZipCodeChange function we will check conditions as per your requirement. If all the requirements are fullfilled then we will mark disability of button to false by setting state setZipCodeButtonVisible to false.

Hope this will help you. If you still have any confusion and problem. Please let me know.